# Global `before` and `beforeEach` for mocha?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm using mocha for javascript unit-testing now.

I have several test files, each file has a `before` and `beforeEach`, but they are exactly the same.

How do I provide a global `before` and `beforeEach` for all of them (or some of them)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Declare a `before` or `beforeEach` in a separate file (I use `spec_helper.coffee`) and require it.

spec_helper.coffee

```
afterEach (done) ->
  async.parallel [
    (cb) -> Listing.remove {}, cb
    (cb) -> Server.remove {}, cb
  ], ->
    done()
```

test_something.coffee

```
require './spec_helper'
```

Comment: can you explain a bit, what's happening there?

Answer (score 89):

In the root of the test folder, create a global test helper `test/helper.js` which has your before and beforeEach

```
// globals
global.assert = require('assert');

// setup
before();
beforeEach();

// teardown
after();
afterEach();
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to require it explicitly.  In fact, it'll throw an error because before, beforeEach, etc. won't exist in the required context.  As long as it's included in the test directory, the code should be executed before any of the tests.

Comment: thanks @khoomeister that was for an old version! updated

Comment: I use this, very nice, but I wonder where to find docs on it?

Comment: It's on the Mocha site: "Note that you may also pick any file and add "root" level hooks, for example add beforeEach() outside of describe()s then the callback will run before any test-case regardless of the file its in. This is because Mocha has a root Suite with no name.". Look at [this section, bottom part](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

Comment: Direct link to what @kamituel is talking about: http://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks

Comment: The `beforeEach` is running before each "it" in each file. Is there a `beforeEachFile`?

Comment: Note that now root-level hooks are the preferred way to handle this: https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins

Answer (score 31):

from the [mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks)…

> ### ROOT-LEVEL HOOKS
>
> You may also pick any file and add “root”-level hooks. For example,
>   add beforeEach() outside of all describe() blocks. This will cause the
>   callback to beforeEach() to run before any test case, regardless of
>   the file it lives in (this is because Mocha has an implied describe()
>   block, called the “root suite

All regular `describe()`-suites are first collected and only *then* run, this kinda guarantees this being called first.

```
'use strict'
let run = false

beforeEach(function() {
    if ( run === true ) return
    console.log('GLOBAL ############################')
    run = true
});
```

Remove the run-flag, if you want to see it run each time, before every test.

I named this file `test/_beforeAll.test.js`. It has no need to be imported/required anywhere, but the `.test.` (resp. `.spec.`) in the filename is important, so that your testrunner picks it up…

---

### bonus track 8-): using `mocha.opts` \o/

If there's stuff, you truly only want to set up once before running your tests (regardless which ones...), `mocha.opts` is a surprisingly elegant option! – Just add a `require` to your file (yes, even if it contributes little to mocha, but rather to your test setup). It will run reliably once before:

[image]

( in this example I detect, if a single test or many tests are about to run. In the former case I output every `log.info()`, while on a full run I reduce verbosity to error+warn... )

**Update:**

If someone knows a way, to access some basic properties of the mocha suite that is about to be run in `once.js`, I would love to know and add here. (i.e. my `suiteMode`-detection is lousy, if there was another way to detect, how many tests are to be run…)

Comment: It's now possible to directly access before/after etc. in a required file (looks like mocha is instantiated before it called the required files)

Answer (score 6):

**`mochaHooks` root hook plugin minimal example on Mocha 8**

This mechanism is currently documented at: https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins

It does not work for `before`, only for `beforeEach` however, since `before` is not in the list of available hooks from: https://mochajs.org/#available-root-hooks

Here's a demo:

test/global.js

```
// Root hook.
exports.mochaHooks = {
  beforeEach(done) {
    console.log('mochaHooks.beforeEach');
    done();
  },
};

// Bonus: global fixture, runs once before everything.
exports.mochaGlobalSetup = async function() {
  console.log('mochaGlobalSetup');
};
```

test/mytest.js

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('describe0', function() {
  // Only runs before the current describe.
  before(async () => {
    console.error('before describe 0');
  });
  beforeEach(async () => {
    console.error('beforeEach describe 0');
  });
  it('it 0 0', function() {
    assert.equal(0, 0);
  });
  it('it 0 1', function() {
    assert.equal(0, 0);
  });

  describe('describe 0 0', function() {
    before(async () => {
      console.error('before describe 0 0');
    });
    beforeEach(async () => {
      console.error('beforeEach describe 0 0');
    });
    it('it 0 0 0', function() {
      assert.equal(0, 0);
    });
    it('it 0 0 1', function() {
      assert.equal(0, 0);
    });
  });

  describe('describe 0 1', function() {
    before(async () => {
      console.error('before describe 0 1');
    });
    beforeEach(async () => {
      console.error('beforeEach describe 0 1');
    });
    it('it 0 1 0', function() {
      assert.equal(0, 0);
    });
    it('it 0 1 1', function() {
      assert.equal(0, 0);
    });
  });
});
```

Then you enable that file with `--require`:

```
npx mocha --require test/global.js test/
```

Outcome:

```
mochaGlobalSetup


  describe0
before describe 0
mochaHooks.beforeEach
beforeEach describe 0
    ✓ it 0 0
mochaHooks.beforeEach
beforeEach describe 0
    ✓ it 0 1
    describe 0 0
before describe 0 0
mochaHooks.beforeEach
beforeEach describe 0
beforeEach describe 0 0
      ✓ it 0 0 0
mochaHooks.beforeEach
beforeEach describe 0
beforeEach describe 0 0
      ✓ it 0 0 1
    describe 0 1
before describe 0 1
mochaHooks.beforeEach
beforeEach describe 0
beforeEach describe 0 1
      ✓ it 0 1 0
mochaHooks.beforeEach
beforeEach describe 0
beforeEach describe 0 1
      ✓ it 0 1 1


  6 passing (6ms)
```

So we see that the global hook ran before every local `beforeEach`.

For `before` I couldn't find a better solution than defining a helper and calling it from every `before`: [How can I make Mocha load a helper.js file that defines global hooks or utilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191243/how-can-i-make-mocha-load-a-helper-js-file-that-defines-global-hooks-or-utilitie)

Tested on mocha 8.3.2, Node v14.16.0.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issue when I needed to "mock" global variables used by one of dependencies.

I used .mocharc.js for that, since code in that JS file is being executed once when "mocha" environment is being setup.

Example .mocharc.js:

```
global.usedVariable = "someDefinedValue";

/** other code to be executed when mocha env setup **/

module.exports = {};
```

This worked for me, nevertheless this looks quite "dirty" way to do that. 
Please, comment if you know a better place for that code :)

Answer (score -2):

The use of a modules can make it easier to have a global setup/teardown for  your test suite. Here is an example using RequireJS (AMD modules):

First, let's define a test environment with our global setup/teardown:

```
// test-env.js

define('test-env', [], function() {
  // One can store globals, which will be available within the
  // whole test suite.
  var my_global = true;

  before(function() {
    // global setup
  });
  return after(function() {
    // global teardown
  });
});
```

In our JS runner (included in mocha's HTML runner, along the other libs and test files, as a `<script type="text/javascript">…</script>`, or better, as an external JS file):

```
require([
          // this is the important thing: require the test-env dependency first
          'test-env',

          // then, require the specs
          'some-test-file'
        ], function() {

  mocha.run();
});
```

`some-test-file.js` could be implemented like this:

```
// some-test-file.js

define(['unit-under-test'], function(UnitUnderTest) {
  return describe('Some unit under test', function() {
    before(function() {
      // locally "global" setup
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
    });

    afterEach(function() {
    });

    after(function() {
      // locally "global" teardown
    });

    it('exists', function() {
      // let's specify the unit under test
    });
  });
});
```