# Supertest, test secure REST API

Tags: node.js, jwt, supertest, express-jwt

I am writing an integration test for a REST API protected by a `jwt`.
One API operation POST `/user/token` is returning a `jwt` given a `username` and a `password` and this token is then used for a list of operations such as:

```
GET /user/:id
```

Where the route is using `jwt({secret: secret.secretToken})`, so the token is included into the HTTP header `Authorization`.

When testing with supertest, I can have nested testing but I want to first get the token, then use this token for testing other operations.

```
POST /user/token => 12345
GET /user/:id, `Authorization Bearer 12345`
GET /user/:foo, `Authorization Bearer 12345`
```

How to avoid generating a new token for every operation testing (see below) but use only a single one generate by POST /user/token.

```
it('should get a valid token for user: user1', function(done) { 
  request(url)
    .post('/user/token')
    .send({ _id: user1._id, password: user1.password })
    .expect(200) // created
      .end(function(err, res) {
        // test operation GET /user/:id
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You want to perform single POST to `/user/token` and then use the token received in every test case? If so, then use the `before` hook of the test framework you are using (Mocha?) and store the token to a variable, e.g.

```
describe('My API tests', function() {

  var token = null;

  before(function(done) {
    request(url)
      .post('/user/token')
      .send({ _id: user1._id, password: user1.password })
      .end(function(err, res) {
        token = res.body.token; // Or something
        done();
      });
  });

  it('should get a valid token for user: user1', function(done) { 
    request('/get/user')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

Comment: How to achieve this if we have multiple files and folders with unit tests dispersed in them, without repeating the token getting in each file?

Comment: @SirBenBenji I think you just need to define the hook so that you can `require` it where needed, eg. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10561632 would work. See also https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours

Answer (score 3):

Need to set **Authorization** as  'Bearer ' + token

```
 var token = null;

 before(function(done) {
    request(url)
      .post('/user/token')
      .send({ _id: user1._id, password: user1.password })
      .end(function(err, res) {
        token = res.body.token; // Or something
        done();
      });
  });


 it('should get a valid token for user: user1', function(done) { 
    request('/get/user')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
      .expect(200, done);
  });
```