# Node: Executing async functions on mocha startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

In my test environment I'm using `mocha` as my test runner. I have configured the `NODE_ENV` as "test" in a `setup.js` file which I configured to run with mocha on start up using

```
mocha --require setup.js
```

I am using `sequelize` as my ORM and I want it to init with the `force` flag set to true. Where should I execute the `sync` function?

```
import models from '../src/data/models';
models.sync({
  force: true
});
```

Since it is an async function, the tests may start before the syncing stage finished.

Comment: You need to use a before hook. Since sync returns a promise you should write

    before(function() { return models.sync({ force: true }) })

Comment: Where should I write this hook? I don't have a main file that holds all the tests, I execute the tests like this: `mocha \"src/**/*.test.js\" --require test/setup.js --compilers js:babel-register`

Comment: I commented below about how you should be explicitly rebuilding your DB for every test that depends on the DB. If you are still interested in some global hook I recommend you check our another answer I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191243/how-can-i-make-mocha-load-a-helper-js-file-that-defines-global-hooks-or-utilitie/36266849#36266849 -- basically you can write a global hook by placing it outside of any describe blocks. Again I don't really recommend it since it isn't explicit and hard to track mutations but up to you...

Answer (score 1):

Add any initialization or code that you need run prior to your tests running to the global `before` handler.

```
before(function () {
  //models code here
  return models.sync({});
})
```

Comment: Where do I write this `before`? I have many before handlers in my test files, but I don't have a primary file that include all the tests.

Comment: I would add a helpers file that you can `require` on any test that needs this to be setup.

Comment: But `sync` is an expensive process, I would like it to happen only once before all the tests.

Comment: Ideally you should be tearing down and rebuilding a DB before every single test. The reason is then you have a perfect picture of the state of the DB prior prior to each test. Otherwise you would have to track mutations throughout the test suite to track down potential bugs. It will take longer to run you tests but it will take much less time to write and debug tests -- which is completely worth it